# Store Active Directory Users in a SQL Database

Tags: active-directory, sql

I need to set a server that creates self-signed certificate when a user register in. So i thought to create a new AD account every time a new users register to the server. BUT, I need to store the user information into a sql server and i can't find a way to do this.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to store the info in a SQL database as opposed to querying AD for info?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "when a user register in"? Are you talking about some application you are working on?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on an web service application. This application requires a mutual authentication (SSL), but the certificate must be provided by the server when a user register into my service. I've already found a way to do a "Active Directory Mapping" between an AD user and a certificate, but i don't want to store the users information into AD, i want to store the users information into a DB.

Comment: If you want to map AD users to certificates, you *need* AD users, so their informations are already stored there. Anyway, what's the problem with simply populating a database table with the informations you need?

Comment: My problem is that i think that store "public users" (that can register from the web) information into AD is insicure, so i'm trying to find another way to do that "mapping",

Comment: This is probably more related to application development than system administration. People will be able to help you more on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you describe and your comment:
`My problem is that i think that store "public users" (that can register from the web) information into AD is insicure, so i'm trying to find another way to do that "mapping", – Stefano`

What you *seem* to need is an AD domain with a [one-way trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961481.aspx):

- Your public users are in domain A.
- Domain A trusts your internal private domain B.
- Your app does AD authentication against domain domain A, and your internal users can authenticate using their full domain credentials (the request gets passed to domain B, which says yay or nay).

Note that this is coming from a guy who hasn't used Windows in a very long time.
I could be giving you terrible advice (and if I am I'm sure one of our Windows folks will clobber me for it).

Comment: He's also going to need to pay for a CAL for every external user.

Comment: @mfinni true - CALs can get expensive.  Then again if you're charging your external users... :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be storing external users for an application, you should be using AD LDS (formerly ADAM) instead of real AD. Or any other generic LDAP, really, but AD LDS is a lot like AD and might fit your needs better.

Comment: How do i create a mapping IIS-AD LDS certificate? So that IIS service recognises a "AD-LDS" user certificate?

Comment: Again: if you want automatic mapping between users and certificates, you *NEED* user accounts.

Comment: If that's your question, you should be over on SO. Voting to move.